# dowloading file rom web server using Alamofire

Tags: swift, download, alamofire

I'm developping a macos App written in swift which can upload and download files from a distant location.

Uploading is correct, but for downloading, when I do it from a local server, there is no problem, but from a distant server I only get 603 octets, whatever is the size of the file.

I'm not sure that this comes from my swift function (as it works with a local server).
My swift function is as following:

```
public func downloadFile(request: BaseRequest, progressIndicator: NSProgressIndicator?, completion: @escaping(NetworkResult<String,  NSString>) -> Void) {
        #if DEBUG
        print(request.parameters["filename"]?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) ?? "Networking.downloadFile problème URL")
        #endif
        if let progressIndicator = progressIndicator {
            progressIndicator.isIndeterminate = false
            progressIndicator.minValue = 0
            progressIndicator.maxValue = 1
            progressIndicator.startAnimation(self)
        }
        if let filename = request.parameters["filename"], let displayName = request.parameters["displayname"], let url = URL(string: filename.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!) {
            let destination: DownloadRequest.Destination = { _, _ in
                var documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
                documentsURL.appendPathComponent(displayName)
                //print(documentsURL)
                return (documentsURL, [.removePreviousFile])
            }
            AF.download(url, to: destination)
            
                .downloadProgress(queue: .main, closure: { (progress) in
                    if let progressIndicator = progressIndicator {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            progressIndicator.doubleValue = progress.fractionCompleted
                        }
                    }
                })
            
                .responseData {
                    response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .failure(let error):
                        completion(NetworkResult.failure(NSString(string: error.errorDescription!)))
                    case .success(_):
                        completion(NetworkResult.success(response.fileURL?.path ?? ""))
                    }
                    
                }
            
        } else {
            completion(NetworkResult.failure(NSString(string: "Impossible de récupérer le fichier, requête \(request)")))
        }
    }
```

Is there something special to implement on the web server (the web server is installed on 1and1)

Answer (score 0):

Forget my question, the problem came about rights of the file I wanted to download. Rights have to bee 0505 and not 0606

Comment: Then please delete the question.